# How to change an object's attribute onclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, attributes

I'm trying to make an object called newBulletin get a new/different key/value pair, "location," when a checkbox on a form is checked, and to make a div's display in css change from "none" to "block" when the form is submitted. The form being submitted should also add newBulletin to an array.

Right now I have two functions that are being reached but aren't changing the object's attribute or the div's css.
This is the code that I have for the div:

```
<div class="posting-form" id="bulletin-form">

            <form onsubmit="appendNewBulletin()">
                <ul>
                    <li>Location:</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Home" id="add-home" onclick="addLocation('Home')"/>
                        <label for = "add-home">Home</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <button type="submit"> submit</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

And this is the script I have so far:

```
<script>
        const bulletinArray = [];
        let newBulletin;


        function addLocation(location) {
            document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = 'point 1';
            newBulletin.location = "Home";
            document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = 'point 2';
        }

        function appendNewBulletin() {
            // document.getElementById("post1").style.display = 'block';
            if(newBulletin.location === "Home") {
                document.getElementById("post1").style.display = 'block';
            }
            document.getElementById("post1").style.display = 'block';
            bulletinArray.push(newBulletin);
        }
</script>
```

Right now I'm hardcoding the location as the word "Home." In the addLocation function,  point 1 is printed, not point 2, so the line in between is probably what's wrong, and when the first line in appendNewBulletin is commented out the div "post1" stays at display:none. I tried using setAttribute instead of assigning newBulletin.location = "Home" and using brackets instead of dot notation, but no dice.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Edit: removed part of a question that was answered in a comment

Comment: Are you saying you want to add a key/value pair to newBulletin so newBulletin.location = "home"?

Comment: Consider using a `data-` attribute, which can be set and retrieved via the `dataset` property. Also, setting `innerHTML` twice in the same function, with no pause, is unlikely to change the `innerHTML` the first time in any meaningful way.

Comment: Your flickering problem is because you are using the form submit event handler but not actually stopping the form from being submitted. So after your javascript is being ran, the form is actually being submitted. There are many solutions to that. You can have your submit button set to type and detect on click of that as one solution. Or change your onsubmit to **onsubmit="appendNewBulletin();return false"** so it doesn't actually submit the form

Comment: Also to append to an array. just use **bulletinArray.push(newBulletin);** you won't need a counter variable.

Comment: imvain2 Thanks, that solved the flickering and appending. I am trying to add a key/value pair to newBulletin, if newBulletin.attribute === "Home" is true by the end of addLocation then addLocation is fully functional.

Comment: Sorry, *newBulletin.location === "Home"